# What is the potential difference between these two points in the given uniform electric field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

So I have been given a uniform electric field $\vec{E}=20 V/m$ in the direction as show in the image. I have been told to calculate the potential difference $VC - VA$. According to the teacher (on YouTube) the potential difference $VC - VA = -10\sqrt{2}V$. But I say it's $-20 V$ as electric field is conservative and I can find potential difference as work done in moving a unit charge from $A$ to $D$ then to $C$. Potential difference between $D$ and $A$ should be a big zero as we are moving perpendicular to the field and potential difference between $C$ and $D$ is $-20V$ so the overall potential difference between $C$ and $A$ should be $-20V$ and not $-10\sqrt{2}$.

Edit: They used $\Delta V = -\vec{E}\cdot\Delta\vec{r}$, and put in the values  $\Delta V = -(20)(1)cos(45)=-10\sqrt{2}$
[image]

Comment: It is similar to when an object is lifted to a height in gravitational field. And in your case it is the altitiude AB or DC mulitplied by E gives V. $V= -20$. How did he or she get $-10 \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: They used $\Delta V = -\vec{E}\cdot\Delta\vec{r}$, and put in the values  $\Delta V = -(20)(1)cos(45)$.

Comment: But $r$ should be $ sec(45)$ if you are taking it diagonally therefore, $V = -(20)(1)sec(45)cos(45) = -20$

Comment: You should check if 1m is diagonal or side. Maybe this is where your teacher made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If 1m is the measure of each side of the square, you are right and they are wrong, $\Delta V=-20V$

To give an interpretation to their answer, one has to assume that 1m is the length of the **diagonal** AC of the square.

In that case, indeed $\Delta V=-(20)(1)cos(45)$ where the (1) is the length of AC and then the factor $cos(45)$ is correct.

But from the drawing, it seems clear that 1m is the length of a **side** of the square, not of the **diagonal** AC.  I was just trying to explain what might have been the mistake of those who proposed the problem.